# Getting a bad status error response with MockMvc junuit test

Tags: java, junit, error-handling, mockmvc

I wrote a test in spring mockMVC this method, but I am getting a wrong error message:

My method testing is:

```
    @Test
    public void registerAll_NoSalons_SalonNoExist() throws Exception {
        KidDTO kidDTO = MockDTO.buildKidDTO();
        kidDTO.setId(null);
        List<KidDTO> kidDTOList = Collections.singletonList(kidDTO);

        given(kidService.saveKid(any(KidDTO.class))).willThrow(SalonNotFoundException.class);
        given(guestLookUpConfig.getChildAge()).willReturn(MAX_KID_AGE);
        given(guestLookUpConfig.getAdultAge()).willReturn(MIN_GUARDIAN_AGE);
        given(dataPropertiesConfig.getQuestions()).willReturn(ModelMock.buildQuestionList(10));

        executeRegisterTodosRequest(kidDTOList, status().isInternalServerError());
    }


private void executeRegisterTodosRequest(List<KidDTO> kids, ResultMatcher expectedStatus) throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(KID_REGISTER_ALL_PATH)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(kids))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(expectedStatus);
    }

    CHILD_REGISTER_ALL_PATH = "/child/all"
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status 
    Expected :500
    Actual   :400
```

This is my SalonNotFoundException:

```
public class SalonNotFoundException extends MiddlewareException {

    private String errorCode = "KC-0009";
    private String userMessage = "There are no Salons registered for this kid's age.";
    private Integer httpStatus = INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value();
    private String message = "Salons not found for the kid's age.";

    public SalonNotFoundException(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Spring MVC controller wraps the 'SalonNotFoundException' in a generic exception with status code 400. At 'kidService' level the 'SalonNotFoundException' is indeed thrown, but the controller is not throwing it forwar. In the unit test you are reading the status code of the generic exception (400).

In case the expected status code sent by the controller is 500, you should modify the controller accordingly. If still in doubt, please add the source code of the controller.